# Difference between char pointer and pointer to char?

Tags: c, pointers

I want to know the difference between char pointer and pointer to char..?
Are they same? If no what is the difference?

Comment: I'd say "same".  If you're in C++ land, using a "const" qualifier, then there are subtle distinctions in your declaration for "pointer is const" vs. "what's pointed at is const".  But as far as your question: the two terms are equivalent.  IMHO..

Answer (score 5):

I think there is no difference between a "pointer to char" and a "char pointer".

```
char *p;
```

Both are just different ways to designate a pointer to `char` type.

Answer (score 4):

This question might make more sense if you backed it up with example code.  As far as I'm concerned they mean the same thing, but I only ever think of "char pointer".

What I think you might mean is this:

```
char c = 'A';
char *pc = &c;            // <-- "pointer to char"?
char *p = new char [50];  // <-- "char pointer"?
```

In fact, `pc` and `p` above are both char pointers.  They can both be used as arrays, although addressing anything other than the zeroth element of `pc` is going to cause problems.

Answer (score 2):

`char pointer` and `pointer to a char` are same i.e. `char *ptr;`

but, if you mean pointer to char *array* then their is a difference.

pointer to char array is declared as `char (*ptr)[n]` which stores the address of an char array of size n.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between the char pointer and pointer to char. Both are same. Normally text strings are represented in C by arrays of characters. Since arrays can be easily be manipulated by pointers it is often used.

Answer (score 2):

The confusion arises when you replace `char` with `double`.  People colloquially use *double pointer* to mean *pointer to pointer to some type*, not *pointer to double type*.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference.
They are just written in a different way.

Comment: Why would they be written differently? Or you mean 'it's an alternative expression'?